# How to add Recently visited product in product page left column?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sidebar, column, related-products

I want to show recently visited product in product page left column. I am new for magento page customization. Can you guide me a right way?

Working code,

[image]
Output:

[image]

Now i want to show product image also. Can you guide me for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `CMS > Widgets`. Click "Add New Widget Instance" and do the following settings:

[image]

Click `Continue`

[image]

Click `Save`. Now check front-end product page.

[image]

**NOTE: Browse two or more product first then check at product page**

From you sample code, try to add this code before `<p class="product-name">`

```
<a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(50) ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

Comment: thanks, it's working. But it will show the product name only. I want to show product image with name. Can you help me for that.

Comment: check second screenshot, select "Viewed Products Images and Names Template" for Template dropdown. It's clearly shown there

Comment: But I have only two options under template 1. Viewed products grid template and 2.Viewed Products List template

Comment: which setting have you selected for Template dropdown ?

Comment: Viewed products grid template

Comment: magento version ? 1.9.x ? Viewed products grid already has code to display images . Also check by clearing cache

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: thanks its working, previously i was selected my own theme, that's why i can't see that options.